# Dynamic classname component in bit dev

Tags: reactjs, bit.dev

I have a next JS project dependency with bit dev components with my organization. Can those components load tailwind classes from next js project with their own tailwind config?

I've tried with using classnames but that doesn't help.

like this repos:
https://github.com/bit-demos/base-ui

Comment: you can definitely use Tailwind in a Bit environment. We have some documentation on this you can follow along with: https://bit.dev/blog/integrating-tailwind-css-and-bit-for-component-styling-lgntqstt.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.